# add Strings to a var pickerDataSource : [String] = [String]()

Tags: ios, swift

I integrated a UIPickerView in my view and I want to add Strings dynamically.

here is my var declaration

```
var pickerDataSource : [String] = [String]()
```

how do I add String in a for statement ? such as

```
            for anItem in json as! [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] {
            let nom = anItem["nom"] as! String
            let prenom = anItem["prenom"] as! String
            //add new String to pickerDataSource
}
```

Comment: Use the `append` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
pickerDataSource.append(prenom)
```